# How do you connect to AWS Cognito in Swift for user signing up and logging in?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm going to start this question by apologizing for such an open ended question, but I am really struggling and all the documentation is outdated.

Amazon's provided sample app hasn't been updated and I get nothing but errors when attempting to run it. I have a login page setup and ready to go with email and password, and I have tried this code:

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
    if (emailTextField.text != nil) && (passwordTextField.text != nil) {
        let user = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).userPool!.getUser(emailTextField.text!)
        user.getSession(emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, validationData: nil, scopes: nil).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {
            (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

            if task.error == nil {
                // user is logged in - show logged in UI
            } else {
                // error
            }

            return nil
        })
    } else {
        // email or password not set
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I'm getting App Delegate has no member "userPool" errors. It does though! I am very new at this, and I have searched github and read through all of Amazon's samples, but the documentation is either in Objective-C, or outdated and doesn't work properly.

Any help with this would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the definition of `userPool` in the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? If so, could you provide the definition Pratik suggested?